# switching between values with .each in a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview, actionviewhelper

I remember seeing a rails method that was something like:

```
<%= toggle(["hello", "i", "am"]) %>
```

and if  put in a `.each` like this:

```
<% @something.each do |s| %>
    <%= toggle(["hello", "i", "am"]) %>
<% end %>
```

it should produce the following:

```
hello i am
```

I've been searching through documentation online and can't find this method but I know I've seen it somewhere.  Does anyone know what the actual method is?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`cycle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) method.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  thank you